# DoCmd.TransferDatabase gives a Type Mismatch error importing dBase IV tables

Tags: ms-access, import, vba, ms-access-2007, dbase

Code I found and modified:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub DoImport()

Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String
 Dim strTable As String
 Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

 blnHasFieldNames = True

strPath = "C:\mypath\"

strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.dbf")
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
    strPathFile = strPath & strFile
    strTable = Left(strFile, Len(strFile) - 4)
    DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "dBase IV", _
        strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames
    strFile = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

It gives a Type Mismatch error every time on the `DoCmd.TransferDatabase` command.  I have added a `Watch`, and made sure that all the variables are correct.  I can't see what's going on to make this fail.

I'm trying to import about 20+ dBase IV files at once.  I am executing using Control-G and then running.  Access 2007.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `ObjectType` parameter in your `TransferDatabase` call.

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "dBase IV", _
    strTable, acTable, strPathFile, ...
              ^^^^^^^
```

In addition, `TransferDatabase` has no parameter `hasFieldNames`. See [DoCmd.TransferDatabase Method (Access)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196455%28v=office.15%29.aspx) for the syntax:

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase _
    TransferType, _
    DatabaseType, _
    DatabaseName, _
    ObjectType, _
    Source, _
    Destination, _
    StructureOnly, _
    StoreLogin)
```